# Dropzonejs rails doesn't render js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, dropzone.js

Hi i need to upload images with dropzone js to my website. i am using
[dropzonejs rails gem](https://github.com/ncuesta/dropzonejs-rails) it uploads correctly but after upload it doesn't render js.erb file

my js.coffee

```
Dropzone.options.photoDropzone =
  paramName: "paper[paper]"
  maxFilesize: 10
  addRemoveLinks: true
  init: ->
    @on "removedfile", (file) ->
      if file.xhr
        $.ajax
          url: "" + ($("#photo-dropzone").attr("action")) + "/" + (JSON.parse(file.xhr.response).id)
          type: "DELETE"
```

my form

```
  = form_for @paper, url: multiple_upload_papers_path(format: :js), remote: true, multipart: true, method: :post,  html: {class: :dropzone, id: 'photo-dropzone'} do |p|
    = p.hidden_field :id
```

my controller action

```
def multiple_upload
    @paper = Paper.new
    @paper.paper = params[:paper][:paper]
    @paper.save
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

and my js.erb file has

```
console.log('Successfull');
```

line. It is working correctly it uploads all images but it doesn't render js.erb file after upload. When i check from chrome console it returns js but it doesn't runs it.

[image: chrome console result]

Comment: Having the same problem.  Headers problem, perhaps...

Comment: i couldn't solve that problem, i tried to set header but it doesn't work. i used .on("success", function(file, response) {} method of dropzone.js

Comment: Yeah, me neither.  I'm using remotipart now.  https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart

Answer (score 5):

just add this to your Dropzone options

```
   success: function (response) {
                eval(response.xhr.response);
            }
```